# NGINX reverse-proxy in front of Domino server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, ibm-domino

I am trying to implement a reverse-proxy in front of a Domino server.
The webmail URI is at `http://domino/Mail`, meaning the base URI is `http://domino/`. With that in mind, I created the following config for NGINX:

```
upstream webmail {
     server 192.168.32.1:80; #internal Domino IP
}

server {
    listen 80;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/mail.access.log;
    error_log             /var/log/nginx/mail.error.log;

    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    proxy_read_timeout      90;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect http://domino http://frontend;

    location / {
        proxy_pass              http://webmail;
    }
}
```

But with this config, a user would always have to enter `http://frontend/Mail` to access the webmail. Modifying the line to read:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass              http://webmail/Mail;
    }
```

Is also not possible, since once a user has accessed their mailbox, the URI will read `http://frontend/mail`.

I am not sure how I can modify or add a location to redirect all queries to `http://frontend/` to `http://frontend/Mail` without causing URIs like `http://domino/Mailsomefileondomino` to be passed to the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add to following:

```
 location / {
        proxy_pass http://webmail/;
    }

    location = / {
        proxy_pass http://webmail/Mail;
    }
```

With `= /` it checks for the exact path

Answer (score 0):

1. To redirect all traffic from / only on http://frontend/ to http://frontend/Mail add

   ```
   location = / {
       return 301 http://frontend/Mail;
   }
   ```

   This will work because nginx does match `=` locations before other locations. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238377/nginx-location-priority).
2. To proxy_pass all requests for http://frontend/* to internal domino server keep this section

   ```
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://webmail;
   }
   ```

additional note: consider securing webmail access by using https.